# Error 404 when connecting to websocket

Tags: jakarta-ee, websocket

This is my ServerEndpoint:

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/mediador")
public class Mediador {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Mediador.class.getName());

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Throwable t) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Método Mediador.onOpen");
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Session aclientSession, Throwable aThrowable) {
        System.out.println("Error : " + aclientSession);
        System.out.println("Error :" + aThrowable);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Throwable t) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Método Mediador.onMessage");
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Throwable t) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "Método Mediador.onClose");
    }

}
```

And this is my websocket client:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + document.location.host + "/chp/mediador");
// also tried this
// var ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + document.location.host + "/mediador");
console.log(ws);

ws.onerror = function (event) {
    console.log("error " + ws);
};

ws.onopen = function (evento) {
    console.log("abierto");
    ws.send("hola");
}

ws.onmessage = function (evento) {
    console.log(evento.data);
}
```

I wrote this code in my jsf template so all my pages in my JSF application run it.

When I try to connect I get the following error:

WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/chp/mediador' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Comment: change `ws://localhost:8080/chp/mediador` to `ws://localhost:8080/mediador`

Comment: Trying using this instead `var ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + document.location.host + document.location.pathname + "mediador");`

Comment: Which server impl/version?

Comment: Already tried ws://localhost:8080/mediador and "ws://" + document.location.host + document.location.pathname + "/mediador" but get the same error.

Comment: I'm using Tomcat 8.0.15

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes things are solved alone...

Perhaps it was a libraries issue. I have made a clean and then deploy and now it's running.

Thanks!